# Server started but not redirecting to the liferay welocme page

Tags: eclipse, liferay, portlet

I am new to liferay. I have changed my userId in liferay portal. From  then If I start the server it is not redirecting me to liferay welcome page. When I type localhost:8080 in the browser I am getting an error that

"Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

```
This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies."
```

> cookies are enabled and tried in chrome also but not working.
>   tried with changing the portal-setup-wizard.properties also.

Where I went wrong..

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Is there any error logs in log console??

Comment: Hi..follwing is the error in console.....Jun 15, 2014 11:55:14 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib....Thanks for the quick reply

Comment: And one more thing...I have unchecked the default privileges for guest role in my portal page along with changing my login credentiels...

Comment: What all default privileges are removed for guest??

Comment: I have dropped the lportal database and restarted the server..and it's working now...Thank you so much for the reply